# Is it OK to write "Good to see you" in an email or Facebook message?

Tags: grammaticality, email, salutations

An old friend of mine wrote some greetings to me on facebook. Now if I want to answer his greetings, is it OK to write the following?

> "Hi, John, good to see you again"

Because I don't "see" him by e-mail or when writing a facebook message. What would be the correct way to write that expression?

Comment: Good to speak with you again?

Comment: Good to hear from you again?

Comment: Are those expressions OK? Maybe I'm too logical. "Good to read from you again" is OK?

Comment: No, that sounds weird.  The ones I said would sound perfectly normal on Facebook.  *Good to hear from you* doesn't literally mean to *hear*.  It's used in letters, emails, texts, etc all the time.

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be okay? It's perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it so much. You obviously mean "nice to meet you [over some medium] again" from the context, and "good to see you" is perfectly okay even if you're not really "seeing" them.

Answer (score 1):

Blind people say things like "See you tomorrow",
so I think we can consider that the word "see" is being used in a non-literal sense.

P.S. You're asking what's correct English for an e-mail or Facebook? 
Tell me, have you ever written "ROTFL" when you weren't *really* rolling on the floor?

Answer (score 0):

If I receive an e-mail from an old friend, I would respond:

*"It's good to hear from you again."*  even though the communication was character-only *(no audio clip)*

I would not use *"It's good to see you again."* even if a picture was included in the communication.